# How does @Html.BeginForm() work? and search result in Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 5 tutorial?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on MVC 5 Asp.Net and following [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search) tutorial. I am wondering how the heck does this fetch the result when I click the Filter button?

There comes a point where this code is added in Movie/view/Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
     <p> Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />   
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> 
}
```

Now as far as I know, it creates a textbox and a button on screen. But how is this button calling the search(index) function and passing the value of textbox in the function, I could not get this.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's not a stupid question. `@html.BeginForm()` works like this. It has some parameters you could add to it like `Action` `Controller` `FormType` `htmlAttributes`. The way it works is that if you leave it empty it will look for a post action with the same name that on the page you are now, for example if you are in on the login page, it will look for a login post action.  I always write what `action` and `controller` I want it to access.

```
@Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "my_form"}) {

}
```

So your `post action` should accept parameters that your form contains, and that can be a `Model` ie a `Product`, `ViewModel` or single string parameters. In your case with the search your action should look like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string SearchString) 
{
   //do something here
}
```

Please note here, for the search string to be passed into the method. The name of the `<input>`  has to be the same as the parameter your action takes. So our form should be like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "YOUR CONTROLLER", FormMethod.Post)){    
     <p> Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />   
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> 
}
```

Hope this brings clarity.

Comment: My form is same is I stated in question. Plus the parameter in my action(Index) funtion is "searchString", not "SearchString" (Here S is capital). If capital and small 'S' does not make any difference, then I accept your answer.

Comment: Well, I veryfied the answer by changing case of different alphabets in form code. It still works. Thanks and accepted :)

Comment: Is there a way that I can simply use model parameters? For example I have a model with UserName, UserEmail and want a function with only one parameter - Model.

Comment: What difference does the @using statement make?

Comment: So from your example, what would I do with `new { @class = "my_form"}`? Because I understand the rest, but I don't know what these other **htmlAttributes** are used for. Is `@class` the class for an HTML element or your MVC code?