# ASP.NET MVC variables returning null runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm attempting to build a webapp using Razor pages and ASP.NET MVC. I've built the same program as a console application but have been unable to get it to work as a web app. I'm unsure of exactly what I'm doing wrong and have spent weeks pouring over tutorials and have redone it multiple times. I have a feeling I'm not obtaining my form variables or returning variables correctly but I'm not sure.

I consistently get the error *RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference*, and am unsure what I'm missing. If anyone could help or has any advice I'd be super greatful.

Model:

```
public string newWriting { get; set; }
public string newWord { get; set; }
private static string _userWriting;
private string _userWord;
public int _repeatCount = 0;
```

&

```
public int ProcessCount()
{
    CheckWriting(_userWriting, _userWord);
    return _repeatCount;
}
public void CheckWriting(string _userWriting, string _userWord)
{
    int count = 0;
    string[] _userSplit = _userWriting.Split();
    for(int i = 0; i < _userSplit.Length; i++)
    {
    if (_userSplit[i] == _userWord + "." || _userSplit[i] == _userWord + "," || _userSplit[i] == _userWord + "!" || _userSplit[i] == _userWord + "?" || _userSplit[i] == _userWord)
       {
          count++;
       }
    }
      _repeatCount = count;
  }
```

Views: Form

```
<h1>Add a category</h1>
<p>Add a category here:</p>
<form action="/form/result" method="post">
<label for="newWriting" name="newWriting" type="text">
<input id='newWriting' name="newWriting" type="text">
<label for="newWord" name="newWord" type="text">
<input id='newWord' name='newWord' type='text'>
<button type="submit">Add</button>
```

& Display (which is what returns null)

```
<p> You used @Model.GetUserWord() @Model.GetRepeatCount() number of times.</p>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("/form/result")]
public ActionResult RepeatCount()
{
return View();
}
[HttpPost("/form/result")]
  public ActionResult Create(RepeatCounter viewModel)
  {
    string newWriting= viewModel.newWriting;
    string newWord = viewModel.newWord;
    return View("RepeatCount");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the first 6 lines of your view file. Also, please let us know the line of code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: In `Create`, did you forget to pass `viewModel` to the `View` call?

Comment: @mjwills Views are now posted in full! I also uh, don't know what you mean by passing viewModel to the View call! I've only been learning this for a week or two and I feel completely lost.

Comment: That is the **entire** contents of your view file? What is the **name** of your view file?

Comment: @mjwills Yeah. < : ) The first one is called Form.cshtml (with the path /form) and the second is RepeatCount.cshtml (with the path /form/result).

Comment: I would normally expect lines like `@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
@using Bob.Controllers
@using Bob.Subscribers
@using Bob.Models
@model Bob.BobPageModel` at the top of a cshtml file.

Comment: @mjwills I could adjust it for that, it's just not where I think we are in my class yet! Do you think passing viewModel would assist with my error?

Comment: Yes I think it would help.

Comment: I agree. You will need to build pass the view model in the Get method. I would normally user Html.BeginForm in the view. I would also use Html.TextBox("MyTextBox") instead of the straight html for you're trying. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574312/how-does-html-beginform-work-and-search-result-in-microsoft-asp-net-mvc-5-tu. If you need an example of get and post controller methods you can download my git hub. See example controller here https://github.com/JKerny/pet-store/blob/master/PetStore/Areas/Admin/Controllers/PetsController.cs