# How to pass model value from a view to a controller when clicking on the button in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a model value `Model.CodigoPedido` from the view below to a controller when clicking on the button also at the same time, I want to redirect the user to the same controller that I'm trying to passing that value:

```
@model Status_Pedido.ViewModels.CodigoPedidoViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Consultar";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Inserir_Pedido", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodigoPedido, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodigoPedido, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodigoPedido, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Procurar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Whats the best way to do it? I've tried using

```
<input type="submit" value="Procurar" class="btn btn-default"  
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {Pedido = Model.CodigoPedido})'" />
```

but I'm getting "Null object reference" exception all the time.

Destination controller:

```
public ActionResult Mostrar_Status(string CodigoPedido)
{
    object ResultadoApiJson = RequisicaoApi.GetApiResultadoPedido(CodigoPedido);
    var resultado = JsonApi.FromJson(ResultadoApiJson.ToString());

    List<ListaPedidosViewModel> listaPedidos = new List<ListaPedidosViewModel>();

    if (resultado.Value == null && resultado.OdataMetadata == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ResultNullException = "Houve um erro de conexão com o servidor, por favor tente novamente mais tarde.";
    }
    else if (resultado.OdataCount == 0 && resultado.OdataMetadata != null && resultado.Value != null)
    {
        ViewBag.NoOrderException = "Não foram encontrados pedidos.";
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var pv in resultado.Value)
        {
            listaPedidos.Add(new ListaPedidosViewModel()
                    {
                        Pedido = pv.Pedido,
                        Status = pv.Status,
                        DataPedido = pv.DataPedido,
                        ValorPedido = pv.ValorPedido,
                        NomeCliente = pv.NomeCliente
                    });
        }                
    }

    return View("Index", listaPedidos);
}
```

Comment: Please post how your controllers for this view are configured.

Comment: i just edited the post, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the best practice is to define the `Action` and `Controller` in your `@Html` helper method like this:

```
@Html.BeginForm(Action, Controller, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes) {
}
```

Then any `<input type="Submit">`  button will submit your form to the specified `Action` and `Controller`.

Your controller can then be:

```
public ActionResult Mostrar_Status(CodigoPedidoViewModel model)
{
}
```

And the `CodigoPedido` field should be bound to that model as `model.CodigoPedido`. Here is some more info on `@Html.BeginForm()`: [How does @Html.BeginForm() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574312/how-does-html-beginform-work-and-search-result-in-microsoft-asp-net-mvc-5-tu)

Comment: it really works fine redirecting to my action in another controller, but ```CodigoPedidoViewModel CodigoPedido``` is returning null, so im not getting any results from my method. when i try put Model.CodigoPedido in ```@Html.BeginForm(Action, Controller, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes) {
}``` as fourth argument i get null exception. what am i missing? thx for the help!

Comment: Are you putting that exact line of code in your `.cshtml` file? Replace `Action` with the name of your action, `Controller` with the name of your controller, and any htmlAttribute you may have go in the fourth argument, like `new { id = "pedidoForm" }` or something.

Comment: yea, but i already have that line of code in my .cshtml as you can see, should i put twice?

Comment: @Lucena your controller also needs the CodigoPedidoViewModel mode as a parameter not the string you currently have

Comment: i already made that too, im out of ideas of what to do. ```@using (Html.BeginForm("Mostrar_Status", "Statuspedido", /*new { pedido = Model.CodigoPedido },*/ FormMethod.Post /*,null*/))``` everytime i try to pass a objectroute i got null reference exception for model.CodigoPedido and when i only set action, controller and formmethod arguments, i cant receive the value that i put in input button in my other controller, even if i use ```CodigoPedidoViewModel CodigoPedido``` inside the action, it still returns null, it looks like editorfor doesnt receive any value for me :(

Comment: the weird thing is that i can see Model.CodigoPedido Value on my browse bar, the same value i have put in textbox

Comment: i made this, i switch CodigoPedidoViewModel to String and it worked, im a little confuse but its working now, anyways thx for your support, that @Html.BeginForm() thing was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

The concept is as @F. Serna sampled.

You get a model in a view, by designing the view with the razor html helper and model properties you are going to submit the model object to the controller. If you don’t specify the action and controller name in the form function it will be submitted to the same action from where it comes but in a httppost one.

Answer (score -1):

Add `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CodigoPedido)` inside the form. You should be able to access that in your controller. Let your `Inserir_Pedido` action do whatever it does and end with `RedirectToAction(["action name", arguments);`.

Comment: this RedirectToAction can be helpful, im trying to pass the view model value by overload: string action name, string controller, string objectroute, but im having trouble passing the third argument: ``` return RedirectToAction("Mostrar_Status", "Statuspedido", new = { CodigoPedido = model.CodigoPedido });```

Comment: Try just `model.CodigoPedido` as your third argument.

Comment: model is not recognize in the action :(