# Textbox value is not getting updated in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update the value of the text box after the ajax call is completed.

Here is the action controller method that is being called as a result of my ajax call:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string productId)
{
    ReferencePeriodsModel model = new ReferencePeriodsModel()
    {
          From = "22222"
    };
    return View("Index", model);
}

@model ReferencePeriodsModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.From, new { id ="fromValue", Value = Model.From})
}
```

Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("method", "cont")",
        //dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        
        //cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
           
        },
    });
```

My problem is that the value of the text box is not getting updated to 22222.
I tried removing Value field with no luck .

I inspected the value of model.From and it is set to 22222

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because ajax will not automatically reload your page. What does your ajax request look like?

Comment: @Jasen updated the description too include the ajax call. Is there anyway i can force ajax to refresh the page by using partial views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you wanna use @Html.BeginForm(), there's no need in that case to use an ajax call. Actually that's the main problem, you can't return a view using ajax calls.
You'll find a similar example to yours here: [How does @Html.BeginForm() work? and search result in Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 5 tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574312/how-does-html-beginform-work-and-search-result-in-microsoft-asp-net-mvc-5-tu)

Comment: My form has multiple buttons how would it know which action to call plus i would like to do different actions before and after calling the controller action. i.e block and unblockUI

Comment: Alright so if I you have more than one button and each one should call to a different method then you need to use Ajax. In that case you should send the parameter productId in your ajax call and in the controller you should return a json with the result of the search.  `return Json(new { Response = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`
You should then in your success function look for the input you want to update and set the value . example: `$("#myInput").val(data.Response)`

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. Accepted answer